# Linux command to split each lines in a file based on a character and write only the specified columns to another file

Tags: linux, file, split, command, line

Suppose the input file file.txt is

```
abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno  
pqr/st/u/vwxy/z
bla/123/45678/9
```

How to split the lines based on the character '/' and write the specified columns (here it is second and fourth) to another file so that the file should look like

```
def jkl  
st  vwxy  
123  9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *perl*, for example:

```
cat file.txt | perl -ne 'chomp(@cols = split("/", $_)); print "@cols[1, 3]\n";' > output
```